# Trouble ssh-ing into router

Tags: ssh

I am trying to access my router from the terminal and I keep getting an error.  Does anyone know how to obtain a "publickey?"

[image: Screen capture of terminal command.]

This is the output with the -v option:

[image]

I tried reading through the similar posts on the issue, but found no useful information.  I was able to edit the ssh_config file and un-comment the setting called "PasswordAuthentication yes" to see if that would solve it, but no luck.

Comment: **Where** did you edit the config file, on the router?

Comment: @guntbert The config file on my computer.

Comment: To enable password based ssh logins you need to edit the appropriate config file on your router - the local files have nothing to do with it. How did you install dropbear on your router?

Answer (score 1):

You need to first get ssh to work with normal username and password login.

This could be disabled on your DD-WRT ssh server.

Once you can login with a username/password the next step is to add the public portion of your ssh key to the servers `.ssh/authorized_keys`  file.

This can be done with the handy utility `ssh-copy-id user@hostname`

Comment: The first pic I posted is the result of me trying to login normally.  SSH login is enabled in my router settings.

Answer (score 1):

Run `ssh-keygen` on your client. This will generate keypair for you in the `~/.ssh` directory. The file with the `.pub` ending is the public key. Then go to your router's web interface and add that public key (or paste its contents) to the authorized keys.

Comment: I don't see a place in the router to add a public key.

Comment: @vivid_vibe It should be somewhere there where you enabled the ssh login. I don't use DD-WRT, but [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/SSH#Public_key_method) they describe how to set it up.

Answer (score 1):

Roaming not allowed error can occur if permissions on remote side are too insecure.

Try

```
chmod 755 $HOME
chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh
chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Refer
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45042/server-does-not-accept-public-key-for-ssh-login-without-password

Comment: No luck, but thank you for trying to help me.